# Array is not accessible inside of a dynamic button

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to access an array inside a button I am creating when a new object is created, but the button goes out of array boundaries when I am using him (but accessing the very same index outside of the button yields no problem)

Relevant code (see the category and expense class below):

```
    public void updateExpensesLabels()
    {
        deleteExpensesLabels();
        for (int i = 0; i < categories.Length; i++)
        {
            if (categories[i] != null)
            {
                categories[i].test();
                addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    categories[i].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text));
                };
             }
         }
     }
```

Note that the categories[i] goes trough with no issues and prints the random text it should, but when I have put the test inside the button, the problem crushes when I click the button.

Edit: I made the test a bit more obvious, this time, the output of the code is "The object is not null outside of the button" and than crushes because of index out of array

```
            if (categories[i] == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Its null outside the button code");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Its not null outside the button code");
            }
            addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (categories[i] == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Its null inside the button code");
                }
                categories[i].test();
                categories[i].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text));
            };
```

Edit 2: 
The exception is System.IndexOutOfRangeException
The details -

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=האינדקס נמצא מחוץ לגבולות המערך.
  Source=Budget Managment Prog
  StackTrace:
   at Budget_Managment_Prog.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<updateExpensesLabels>b__0(Object s, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Budget Management Prog\Budget Managment Prog\Budget Managment Prog\Form1.cs:line 213
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Budget_Managment_Prog.Program.Main() in C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Budget Management Prog\Budget Managment Prog\Budget Managment Prog\Program.cs:line 19
```

Forms1 -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Budget_Managment_Prog
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Expenses Section
        /// </summary>
        Category[] categories = new Category[0];
        TabPage[] categoryTab = new TabPage[0];
        Label[] expenseLabel = new Label[0];
        private void addCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            increaseCategories();
            categories[Category.categoryNum] = new Category(Category.categoryNum, newCategoryTextBox.Text);
            Category.categoryNum++;
            increaseTabs();
            updateExpensesLabels();
        }

        private void increaseTabs()
        {
            TabPage[] temp = new TabPage[categoryTab.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < categoryTab.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = categoryTab[i];
            }
            categoryTab = temp;
        }

        private void increaseCategories()
        {
            Category[] temp = new Category[categories.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = categories[i];
            }
            categories = temp;
        }

        public void updateExpensesLabels()
        {
            deleteExpensesLabels();
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.Length; i++)
            {
                if (categories[i] != null)
                {

                    categoryTab[i] = new TabPage();
                    categoryTab[i].Text = categories[i].name;
                    categoryTabControl.Controls.Add(categoryTab[i]);
                    Label addExpenseLabel = new Label(); addExpenseLabel.Text = "New Expense Here?";
                    addExpenseLabel.AutoSize = true;
                    addExpenseLabel.Top = 10; addExpenseLabel.Left = 15; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpenseLabel);
                    Label nameLabel = new Label(); nameLabel.Text = "Name:";
                    nameLabel.AutoSize = true;
                    nameLabel.Top = 25; nameLabel.Left = 25; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(nameLabel);
                    Label amountLabel = new Label(); amountLabel.Text = "Money:";
                    amountLabel.AutoSize = true;
                    amountLabel.Top = 25; amountLabel.Left = 250; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(amountLabel);
                    TextBox expenseName = new TextBox(); expenseName.Top = 50; expenseName.Left = 25; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(expenseName);
                    TextBox expenseAmount = new TextBox(); expenseAmount.Top = 50; expenseAmount.Left = 250; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(expenseAmount);
                    categories[i].test();
                    Button addExpense = new Button();
                    addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        categories[i].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text));
                    };
                    categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpense);
                    int entries = 0;
                    int labelNum = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < categories[i].expenses.Length; j++)
                    {
                        expenseLabel[labelNum] = new Label();
                        expenseLabel[labelNum].Text = Convert.ToString(categories[i].expenses[labelNum].num);
                        expenseLabel[labelNum].Top = 80 + (30 * entries); expenseLabel[labelNum].Left = 25;
                        categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(expenseLabel[labelNum]);
                        increaseLabelArray();
                        labelNum++;


                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void deleteExpensesLabels()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i< categoryTab.Length; i++)
            {
                categoryTabControl.Controls.Remove(categoryTab[i]);
            }
        }

        private void increaseLabelArray()
        {
            Label[] temp = new Label[expenseLabel.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < expenseLabel.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = expenseLabel[i];
            }
            expenseLabel = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Category -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Budget_Managment_Prog
{
    class Category
    {
        private int numOfExpenses = 0;
        public Expense[] expenses = new Expense[0];
        public static int categoryNum = 0;
        public string name;
        public Category(int num1, string name1)
        {
            categoryNum = num1;
            name = name1;
        }

        public void createNewExpense( int expense2, string name2)
        {

            increaseArray();
            expenses[numOfExpenses] = new Expense(numOfExpenses, expense2, name2);
            numOfExpenses ++;           


        }

        public void deleteExpense(int num)
        {
            if (num > expenses.Length || num < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for deletion, make sure the number is not bigger than the biggest person or smaller than 1");
            }
            else
            {
                Expense[] temp = new Expense[expenses.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < expenses.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (expenses[i].num < num)
                    {
                        temp[i] = expenses[i];
                    }
                    if (expenses[i].num > num)
                    {
                        expenses[i].num--;
                        temp[i - 1] = expenses[i];
                    }
                }
                expenses = temp;
                numOfExpenses--;
            }
        }
        public void increaseArray()
        {
            Expense[] temp = new Expense[expenses.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < expenses.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = expenses[i];
            }
            expenses = temp;

        }

        public void test()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Problem is in category or expense classes");
        }
    }
}
```

Expense -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Budget_Managment_Prog
{
    class Expense
    {
        public int num;
        public int expense;
        public string name;
        public Expense(int num1, int expense1, string name1)
        {
            num = num1;
            expense = expense1;
            name = name1;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You have array of length 0. It has no element. You can't access any element as there is nothing and you will get out of bounds.

Comment: What are you talking about? did you read what I said? I just accessed the same index outside of the button code

Comment: Debug your code and look at your array.

Comment: I did and as you said it was at 0, but 0 was declared and I stand by what I said as said index indeed was declared and the test worked fine (which shouldn't happen if the index was null)

Comment: You have declared `public Expense[] expenses = new Expense[0];` then you are trying to `expenses[numOfExpenses] = new Expense(numOfExpenses, expense2, name2);` where the `numOfExpenses` is out of `expenses` length as it is empty array as you have declared.

Comment: @Tomer SPetrosov is correct.  You created an array with length 0.  It has no slots for elements.

Comment: (copy of my comment from the answer below)
Misclick, I am editing, come back in 3 mins. I have edited the code as you said, and made the array start from one, but it still won't fix it, I will go further more and show you this: addExpense.Click += (s, e) => { categories[i].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount‌​.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text)); }; categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpense); The code only crushes when I click on the button even though seeming the same code is initialized just a second before outside of the button.. @Amy

Comment: @tomer Of course it only crashes when you click the button, *but that isn't where the problem is*.  You have an empty array.  It contains zero slots.  **You cannot insert an item into an array if it doesn't have any slots.**  If you want to fix your problem, listening to the feedback you're receiving would be a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED

I found your problem. It's in this `categories[i]`. If you debug the program you will see that when you add `new Category` your `i is 0` and your `categories[i].test()` will work normally. But the problem is in the fact that your `button click` is always after the `loop's iteration` , in other words when `button click` works `i` is already `equal to 1` and your `categories[i]` will go out of bounds.
If you change the part in your code where you add button to this you won't get exception any more:

```
categories[i].test();
var number = i;
Button addExpense = new Button();
addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
{                       
    categories[number].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text));
};
```

---

You have declared

```
public Expense[] expenses = new Expense[0];
```

then you are trying to do this

```
expenses[numOfExpenses] = new Expense(numOfExpenses, expense2, name2);
```

where the `numOfExpenses` is out of `expenses` `length` as it is empty array as you have declared.

I suggest you to use `List<Expense>` instead of `Expense[]`, so it won't be limited by the number that you give while initialization and when you will need to add new Expense you will just use `expenses.Add(new Expense(numOfExpenses, expense2, name2)).`

Here is example how you can do it

```
class Category
{
    public List<Expense> expenses = new List<Expense>();
    public static int categoryNum = 0;
    public string name;
    public Category(int num1, string name1)
    {
        categoryNum = num1;
        name = name1;
    }

    public void createNewExpense(int expense2, string name2)
    {
        expenses.Add(new Expense(expenses.Count, expense2, name2));
    }

    public void deleteExpense(int num)
    {
        if (num > expenses.Count || num < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for deletion, make sure the number is not bigger than the biggest person or smaller than 1");
        }
        else
        {
            expenses.RemoveAt(num);
        }
    }
    public void test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Problem is in category or expense classes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Misclick, I am editing, come back in 3 mins.

I have edited the code as you said, and made the array start from one, but it still won't fix it, I will go further more and show you this:


                    addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        categories[i].createNewExpense(Convert.ToInt32(expenseAmount.Text), Convert.ToString(expenseName.Text));
                    };
                    categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpense);

The code only crushes when I click on the button.

Comment: @Tomer look at the `Category` class I have added to my answer

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that, Thank you

Comment: @Tomer I have added it few minutes before.

Comment: I straight up copied and replaced my code with yours, and tried again, but still I am having the same issue. I know I have said it for countless times but the code that works perfectly outside of the button doesn't work on the inside.
                    `categories[i].createNewExpense(43, "BB");
                    addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        categories[i].createNewExpense(43, "BB");
                    };
                    categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpense);`

Comment: It creates a new expense before the creation of the button, and than crushes when I click on the button only creates a new expense. @S.Petrosov

Comment: Can you please add the Exception to the question with the full stack trace??

Comment: @Tomer Sorry I had mistake in this class `expenses.RemoveAt(num-1);` must be `expenses.RemoveAt(num);`

Comment: I added those in edit 2 (I hope I got what you meant by stack trace), trying to add those lines now.
edit: no change.

Comment: @Tomer what is in line 213 of Form1.cs? in the question Form1 has 112 lines.

Comment: I have cut out the 'salaries' portion of the program as it uses different methods and references.

Comment: Those are the lines 211-215
                    `addExpense.Click += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        categories[i].createNewExpense(43, "BB");
                    };
                    categoryTab[i].Controls.Add(addExpense);`

213 being the line in the button

Comment: @Tomer ok, I found your problem. it's in this categories[i]. If you debug the program you will see that when you add new Category your `i` is 0 and your categories[i].test() will work normally. But the problem is in the fact that your `button click` is always after the `loop's iteration` , in other words when `button click` works `i` is already equal to `1` and your 
categories[i] will go out of bounds.